# Firebase performance monitoring not working with IE11

Tags: javascript, firebase, internet-explorer, angularfire, firebase-performance

I have an angular application and I use angular version 12.0.5. I am using AngularFire to connect with firebase. I tried to enable firebase performance monitoring along with it. But the app fails to load in IE11.
I have already added the polyfills suggested in the documentation of AngularFire

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'then'
```

this is the error that I am getting in the console - IE11.

```
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import "classlist.js"; // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
import "core-js/es/array";
import "core-js/es/object";
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import "core-js/es/reflect";
import "core-js/es/string";
import "core-js/stable";
import "cross-fetch/polyfill";
import "first-input-delay";
import "globalthis";
import "isomorphic-fetch";
/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
import "web-animations-js"; // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
import "zone.js"; // Included with Angular CLI.
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import "./polyfills/proxy.polyfill.js";





(window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
(window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
(window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ["scroll", "mousemove"]; // disable patch specified eventNames

/*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/*
 * To have compatibility across a wide range of environments for AngularFire and Firebase
 * IE 11, Chrome < 71, Safari < 12.1, iOS < 12.2, Node < 12
 */
(window as any).globalThis = window;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
// import "intl"; // Run `npm install --save intl`.
/**
 * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
 */
// import "intl/locale-data/jsonp/en";


if (!Element.prototype.closest) {
  Element.prototype.closest = function (s) {
    let el = this;

    do {
      if (Element.prototype.matches.call(el, s)) { return el; }
      el = el.parentElement || el.parentNode;
    } while (el !== null && el.nodeType === 1);
    return null;
  };

}

/**
 * IE11 "crypto" is undefined error fix
 * Reference: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/issues/113#issuecomment-520033811
 */
if (!window.crypto && (<any>window).msCrypto) {
  (<any>window).crypto = (<any>window).msCrypto;
}
```

This is my current polyfill js. Is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

As of [version 9.8](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_980_-_may_06_2022) of its JavaScript SDK (released last week), Firebase no longer support IE11

You might want to check what version of the JavaScript SDK you're using.

Comment: Good for you! IE11 is history in ~1 month's time. No tears will be shed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am still in version 8.8 of the SDK. that is why the confusion. Looks like a polyfill missing.